# How can I update an HTML table based on dropdown values + calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a very simple app to keep track of the standings of my volleyball group. There are four dropdowns, two for the winning pair and two for the losing pair. I'm able to display the winners and losers, and I've set up a simple table with four columns and an example row:

```
Player | Games | Points | Points per game
Felix      0        0            0
```

[image]

**What I would like to do now and where I'm stuck:**

After clicking "Submit result"

- Add 1 to the number of games for each player that played in the game
- Add 1 to the number of points of the winners
- Update points per game (i.e., divide the total number of points by the number of games)
- Somehow store the current state of the table (via a database, or a .json file or something else?), so that we can continue adding games to it during the summer (I use Replit which offers an always on function for apps, if that helps)

```js
const button = document.getElementById('btn');
const players = ["Laura", "Felix", "Martin", "Hanna", "Simon", "Nora", "Dennis", "David", "Giulia G.", "Giulia M.", "Jackie"];

button.addEventListener("click", async function() {
  logGame(dropDowns);
})

//Populate dropdown menus
let dropDowns = ["player1", "player2", "player3", "player4"];
for (let i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
  let playerDropDown = document.getElementById(dropDowns[i]);

  for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = players[i];
    option.text = players[i];
    playerDropDown.appendChild(option);
  };
};

let winners = []
let losers = []

function logGame(dropDowns) {
  for (i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
    let select = document.getElementById(dropDowns[i])
    let player = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    i <= 1 ? winners.push(player) : losers.push(player)
  }

  return winners, losers
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Volleyball</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="game">
        <div class="form-container">
          <!--  <p>Neuer Spieler:</p>
            <input id="name" class="form-field__short" type="name" name="name"> -->

            <p>Won</p>

            <p>Player 1</p>
            <select id="player1" class="form-field__full" name="player1">
            <option></option>
            </select>

            <p>Player 2</p>
            <select id="player2" class="form-field__full" name="player2">
            <option></option>
            </select>

            <p>Lost</p>

             <p>Player 3</p>
            <select id="player3" class="form-field__full" name="player3">
            <option></option>
            </select>
            
            <p>Player 4</p>
            <select id="player4" class="form-field__full" name="player4">
            <option></option>
            </select>
            <p></p>
            <div id="btn">Submit result</div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Games</th>
        <th>Points per game</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Felix</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Be careful with nested for and index names. When you nest loops, you really should use different letters for counters: `for (let i...) { for (let j ....}}` I know the `let` may save you here, but for the sake of readability. In one loop you forget the var/let and that makes `i` a global var
- `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;` is the same as `select.value`
- Why `async function()`? Nothing async here

Here is a simplified version easier to update

```js
const game = document.getElementById('game');
const dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll('select.form-field__full')
const players = ["Laura", "Felix", "Martin", "Hanna", "Simon", "Nora", "Dennis", "David", "Giulia G.", "Giulia M.", "Jackie"];

game.addEventListener("submit", logGame)


//Populate dropdown menus

dropDowns.forEach(dd => dd.innerHTML = players.map(player => `<option value="${player}">${player}</option>`).join(''));


function logGame(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit for now, later we can Ajax
  let winners = []
  let losers = []
  dropDowns.forEach((dd, i) => {
    if (i <= 1) winners.push(dd.value)
    else losers.push(dd.value)
  })
  console.log(winners, losers)
}
```

```html
<form id="game">
  <div class="form-container">
    <!--  <p>Neuer Spieler:</p>
            <input id="name" class="form-field__short" type="name" name="name"> -->

    <p>Won</p>

    <p>Player 1</p>
    <select id="player1" class="form-field__full" name="player1">
      <option></option>
    </select>

    <p>Player 2</p>
    <select id="player2" class="form-field__full" name="player2">
      <option></option>
    </select>

    <p>Lost</p>

    <p>Player 3</p>
    <select id="player3" class="form-field__full" name="player3">
      <option></option>
    </select>

    <p>Player 4</p>
    <select id="player4" class="form-field__full" name="player4">
      <option></option>
    </select>
    <p></p>
    <button id="btn">Submit result</button>
  </div>
</form>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Games</th>
      <th>Points per game</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Felix</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```